# how can i pre-process .sql files with flyway

Tags: h2, flyway

I am using postgres and h2 for tests in a project.

In .sql files I have "timestamp without time zone" datatype.

h2 doesnt like it.

How can i pre-process my .sql files for flyway in order to.

```
replaceAll("timestamp without time zone", "timestamp");
```

postgres can handle both
h2 can only handle the latter one

Answer (score 0):

I changed my .sql files, to use "timestamp" datatype. So H2 likes it. Postgres likes it too and converts it to "timestamp without time zone".
Files are generated from Enterprise Architect. There I have altered code templates to only generate "timestamp"

Comment: As an alternative you could also have used a placeholder for "without time zone" that we either contain the value for PG or be empty for H2, but in this specific case your solution is even better.